# Solve a non-exact ODE by a different method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following equation

$$(x^3+2xy)dx-x^2dy=0$$

is not exact, since

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=2x\ne\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-2x$$

I wanted to try the following then,

$$-x^2dy=-(x^3+2xy)dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^3+2xy}{x^2}$$
$$dy=\frac{x^3+2xy}{x^2}dx$$
$$\int dy=\int xdx+ \int \frac{2y}{x}dx$$

But the last integral, according to what I suspect does not make any sense for finding a solution to the original problem. That would mean that the answer by this approach is:

$$y=\frac{x^2}{2}+2y\ln x$$

However, this is not correct.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Divide the initial equation by $x^4.$ (I don't see what makes you think " That would mean that the answer by this approach is [etc.]")

Comment: What I mean by that comment is: Why is not that approach correct?

Comment: @AnneBauval in fact, the original eqn is a result of applying already an integrating factor on its "precursor". What is proposed by you, and outlined by gtgh suggests that thus that one can apply the integrating procedure indefinitely. Is that the case for such problems? Apply integrating factors until you have an exact form?

Comment: In general , it is sometimes possible to convert a differential equation that is not exact into an exact differential equation by multiplying the equation by a suitable integrating factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, compute $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}$ and we will get $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}$=-$\frac{4}{x}$
So set the integrating factor Ψ as $e^{-\int\frac{4}{x}dx}$ and we will have
Ψ =$x^{-4}$.
Multiply Ψ =$x^{-4}$ to both sides and you can check that the differential equation after multiplying the integrating factor will be exact.

Comment: Isn't it rather $-\frac 4x$, and $\Psi=x^{-4}$ (like in my comment)? (Btw, Luthier, I am unable to answer you, I had nothing more than "calculus intuition", and being vaguely aware of what gtgh just alluded to in his last comment above.)

Comment: ohh i see my mistake, thanks for the reminder

Comment: @AnneBauval is there a limit to how many integrating factors you may have to seek  to find an exact form?

Comment: Luthier, I don't know (see my reply 33 min ago).

Answer (score 3):

$$(x^3+2xy)dx-x^2dy=0$$
$$x^3dx+ydx^2-x^2dy=0$$
$$\dfrac {dx}{x}+\dfrac  {ydx^2-x^2dy}{x^4}=0$$
$$\dfrac {dx}{x}-d  \left (\dfrac  {y}{x^2}\right)=0$$
Integrate.

Comment: Creative stuff!  This gives $\ln x-\frac{y}{x^2}$. I have never seen such an approach. So you can "split" out $x$ from $dx$? I got $\ln x-2\frac{y}{x^2}$ with the "classic" approach.

Comment: I divided by $x^4$ the original differential equation. You'e welcome. @Luthier415Hz

Comment: The third step was impressive, can you add a step between 3 and 4? It will show your "magic" trick better

Comment: you have to know that $d\dfrac u v=\dfrac {vdu-udv}{v^2}$  here $v=x^2$ and $u=y$ @Luthier415Hz

Comment: Sure, that is a famous form, but the way you juggle with differentials is foreign to me. Really interesting

Comment: You're welcome @Luthier415Hz

Comment: Yep, you seem to juggle with differentials. Incredible stuff.

Comment: Thank you @Luthier415Hz